# Change the selected item index of TileList in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hey guys can we change the index of the selected item. For e.g if we have four tiles in the tilelist and now we want to change the index of the selected item(i.e. 3) to 2. So some one can help me out to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the item in the dataProvider.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try :

```
tileList.selectedIndex = 2;
```